# How to rename a user in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-accounts

I want to rename a user in Windows 7. If there's a utility that does this (rather than follow a long list of instructions), then better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change your user account name, you can easily do it by going to Control Panel, User Accounts and click on "Change your account name".

If you are referring to change the user profile folder name, AFTER changing your account name, you can follow the instructions provided in this [link](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/147545-user-profile-folder-change-user-account-folder-name.html).

Answer (score 0):

for doing it in a command-line you can issue the following command:

```
wmic useraccount where name='old_username' rename new_username
```

ps:

it may require elevated privilege so, so run `cmd.exe` (`wmic.exe` that is, actually) as administrator

pps:

to change the name of the user (instead of the username itself), that is what appears on lock screen:

```
net user username /fullname:"john doe"
```